# asp.net core database connection issue

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I am working in asp.net core 2.1 API and I am following 3-tier architecture. API – Business layer – Data Access Layer

Currently I am facing problem with connecting to database.i am not sure how to pass the connection string from API to DAL. Below the sample code I tried and not working.

```
public class CustomerDB : DbContext
    {

public CustomerDB (DbContextOptions<CustomerDB> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(//ConnectionString);
            }
        }

}
```

Startup .cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            services.AddDbContext<CustomerDB>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
}
```

sample dB call method in DAL:

```
Datatable dtCustomers = new Datatable();
            using (CustomerDB dbConnect = new CustomerDB ())
            {
                dbConnect.Database.OpenConnection();
                DbCommand cmd = dbConnect.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Getcustomers"; 
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //parse and bind the reader data to datatable
                }
                return dtCustomers 
            }
        }
```

Not sure who to get the connection string the pass it to onconfiguring method. i tried to create set the connection string this DAL  level (hard coded) and it worked. like below

```
public class CustomerDB : DbContext
    {

public CustomerDB (DbContextOptions<CustomerDB> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=178.40.132.28;Initial Catalog=customers;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=False");
            }
        }

}
```

but i don't want to hard code in this DAL. it has to come from API. please help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

A connection string should not be in your DAL layer in the first place. You configure your context in the application's startup, and then you inject the context into your repository or whatever needs it. The connection string stays with the app.